per-thread scheduling priority on Linux with default (SCHED_OTHER) scheduling policy
I'm trying to implement a cross-platform wrapper to adjust the current thread priority; on POSIX the "correct" thing seems something like
/// set the priority adjustment for the current thread
/// @param pri  priority between -2 and 2; 0 is the "normal" priority
/// @return true if successful
bool czu::set_thread_priority(int pri) {
    struct sched_param sp;
    int policy;
    pthread_t self = pthread_self();
    if (pthread_getschedparam(self, &policy, &sp) != 0) return false;
    int pmin = sched_get_priority_min(policy);
    int pmax = sched_get_priority_max(policy);
    if (pmin == -1 || pmax == -1) return false;
    sp.sched_priority = pmin + (pmax-pmin) * (pri + 2) / 4;
    return pthread_setschedparam(self, policy, &sp) == 0;
}

This works as I'd expect on macOS (where threads seem to have a priority range [15, 47], with default 31), but does not work at all on Linux, as with the default policy (0 AKA SCHED_OTHER) the range of allowed priorities is [0, 0], i.e. no priority adjustment is possible.
You can switch the scheduling policy to something like SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR and use their priority values, but that's not at all what I want (from man 7 sched they always have priority over SCHED_OTHER tasks, and in general they are suited for very specific scenarios).
I did find out instead that what works is to use the nice value (through nice(2)/setpriority(2)), which, contrary to what POSIX says, is thread-specific instead of process-specific (seems like a pretty direct consequence of the very blurred line between threads and processes on Linux, everything ultimately being just a "task" with various possible shared stuff with other tasks). So I ended up with:
bool czu::set_thread_priority(int pri) {
    if (pri < -2) pri = -2;
    if (pri > 2) pri = 2;
#ifdef _WIN32
    // %pri was conveniently chosen so that it matches SetThreadPriority
    return SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), pri);
#elif __linux__
    // On Linux the pthread_setschedparam stuff works only with particular
    // scheduling policies, specifically it does not work with the default one;
    // instead, nice(2)/setpriority(2) works, and affects only the current
    // thread instead of doing what POSIX would say (whole process).
    // Here the allowed range is [20, -19] (20 = minimum priority); we can
    // ignore clamping -20 as setpriority is already guaranteed to do it.
    return setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, pri*-10) == 0;
#else
    struct sched_param sp;
    int policy;
    pthread_t self = pthread_self();
    if (pthread_getschedparam(self, &policy, &sp) != 0) return false;
    int pmin = sched_get_priority_min(policy);
    int pmax = sched_get_priority_max(policy);
    if (pmin == -1 || pmax == -1) return false;
    sp.sched_priority = pmin + (pmax-pmin) * (pri + 2) / 4;
    return pthread_setschedparam(self, policy, &sp)) == 0;
#endif
}

which seems good enough, but then I noticed in man 2 setpriority:

According to POSIX, the nice value is a per-process setting.  However, under the current Linux/NPTL implementation of POSIX threads, the nice value is a per-thread attribute: different threads in the same process can have different nice values. Portable applications should avoid relying on the Linux behavior, which may be made standards conformant in the future.

So, if I want to be future-proof but still be able to adjust priority of threads with SCHED_OTHER default scheduling policy what am I supposed to do?
A possibility that comes to mind is to work in fallback: run the sched_get_priority_min/sched_get_priority_max dance, and if it turns out that it's [0,0] AND we are on Linux, assume we are in a situation where the nice value is per-thread (the idea is that if the nice value is ever made per-thread, the pthreads stuff should start working as expected, with a usable values range).
bool czu::set_thread_priority(int pri) {
    if (pri < -2) pri = -2;
    if (pri > 2) pri = 2;
#ifdef _WIN32
    // %pri was conveniently chosen so that it matches SetThreadPriority
    return SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), pri);
#else
    struct sched_param sp;
    int policy;
    pthread_t self = pthread_self();
    // on POSIX the admissible priorities range isn't fixed, and depends from
    // the scheduler policy for the thread; let's figure all this out
    if (pthread_getschedparam(self, &policy, &sp) != 0) return false;
    int pmin = sched_get_priority_min(policy);
    int pmax = sched_get_priority_max(policy);
    if (pmin == -1 || pmax == -1) return false;
#ifdef __linux__
    if (pmax - pmin == 0) {
        // On Linux the pthread_setschedparam stuff works only with particular
        // scheduling policies, specifically it does not work with the default
        // one; instead, nice(2)/setpriority(2) works, and affects only the
        // current thread instead of doing what POSIX would say (whole process).
        // Here the allowed range is [20, -19] (20 = minimum priority); we can
        // ignore clamping -20 as setpriority is already guaranteed to do it.
        return setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, pri*-10) == 0;
    }
#endif
    // plain linear interpolation
    sp.sched_priority = pmin + (pmax-pmin) * (pri + 2) / 4;
    return pthread_setschedparam(self, policy, &sp) == 0;
#endif
}

Is there some better possibility/API that I missed?


So, if I want to be future-proof but still be able to adjust priority of threads with SCHED_OTHER default scheduling policy what am I supposed to do?

This is a good question.
The unfortunate fact is that if Linux is ever updated to make niceness a per-process attribute instead of a per-thread attribute then we don't know what provisions will be made to offset the effect on intra-process thread prioritization.  We also don't know whether or how glibc or other C standard libraries might adapt their wrapper functions.  For example, it's possible that Glibc's setpritority() wrapper would be adjusted in some way to continue providing for per-thread prioritization.  Or not.  It's also unclear whetherSCHED_OTHER would acquire a broader range of scheduling priorities.  It's unclear whether a new "normal" scheduling policy might be introduced.

A possibility that comes to mind is to work in fallback: run the sched_get_priority_min/sched_get_priority_max dance, and if it turns out that it's [0,0] AND we are on Linux, assume we are in a situation where the nice value is per-thread (the idea is that if the nice value is ever made per-thread, the pthreads stuff should start working as expected, with a usable values range).

That seems a pretty reasonable approach to me.  I like that it uses the dynamically determined scheduling priority range first, rather than going directly to platform-specific code.  It might nevertheless need to be fixed someday, but with the good accompanying commentary, that nature of any such future issue should be relatively clear to future you or their successor.

Is there some better possibility/API that I missed?

I don't think so.

Thank you, this matches quite well what I thought; to be completely honest, I feel that this is mostly a style exercise, and that per-thread niceness isn't ever going to be changed, as I expect that much code has been written that relies on the current behavior. Maybe pthread_setschedparam/pthread_setschedprio/sched_setparam will become effective on SCHED_OTHER (and in that case my code should work fine), and maybe setpriority will gain some PRIO_PROCESS_REALLY, but as it's like this since the dawn of NTPL and wasn't ever changed I wouldn't hold my breath.

As John Bollinger has said, there's a problem relying on the future, and second guessing it. Any code blob that succesfully abstracts the matter will have to be maintained.
One possibility is to ship code in a deliberately "broken, won't compile" state, so that future adventurers with the code are forced to consider the situation. This could be conditional on last known good (well, understood) versions of libraries / OSes, so that if compiled at or below those it works.
Another possibility is that one could write a "library init" function that tests out platform / library behaviour at application start up, and then remembers underlying API behaviour. I've not thought what that could look like, but it's probably achievable.

«One possibility is to ship code in a deliberately "broken, won't compile" state, so that future adventurers with the code are forced to consider the situation.» the problem here is that this is not really something that can be tested at compile-time, and a thorough testing of the platform behavior is not entirely trivial. It should be done at library init, but ugh it's a pain and quite invasive (the only thing that comes to mind is to spawn a thread, do setpriority there and then check from the main thread if its own priority was changed).
